# Counting consecutive values in rows in R

Tags: r, count, time-series, rows, panel-data

I have a time series and panel data data frame with a specific ID in the first column, and a weekly status for employment: Unemployed (1), employed (0).

I have 261 variables (the weeks every year) and 1.000.000 observations.

I would like to count the maximum number of times '1' occurs consecutively for every row in R.

I have looked a bit at rowSums and rle(), but I am not as far as I know interested in the sum of the row, as it is very important the values are consecutive.

[You can see an example of the structure of my data set here - just imagine more rows and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnXro.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write a little helper function to return the maximum number of times a certain value is consecutively repeated in a vector, with a nice default value of `1` for this use case

```
most_consecutive_val = function(x, val = 1) {
  with(rle(x), max(lengths[values == val]))
}
```

Then we can `apply` this function to the rows of your data frame, dropping the first column (and any other columns that shouldn't be included):

```
apply(your_data_frame[-1], MARGIN = 1, most_consecutive_val)
```

---

If you share some easily imported sample data, I'll be happy to help debug in case there are issues. `dput` is an easy way to share a copy/pasteable subset of data, for example `dput(your_data[1:5, 1:10])` would be a great way to share the first 5 rows and 10 columns of your data.

---

If you want to avoid warnings and `-Inf` results in the case where there are no 1s, use Ryan's suggestion from the comments:

```
most_consecutive_val = function(x, val = 1) {
  with(rle(x), if(all(values != val)) 0 else max(lengths[values == val]))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - it worked, very well! I have two questions though:

1) If no '1's ' appear it returns "-inf". which I assume is because I have not specified what the function should do if there are not any 1's?

2) What is the MARGIN-command for? I have looked it up, but not quite sure I understand :)

Comment: 1) Yes, if there are no 1s, my function essentially ends up running `max()` with no input, which, if you try it out, you will see returns `-Inf`. 2) `MARGIN = 1` means "apply this function to each row". `MARGIN = 2` means "apply this function to each column. You can do more complicated things if you have higher-dimensional arrays, but in common cases that's all you need to know.

Comment: I'd also add a word of caution with `apply` - it is made for use with matrices, not data frames. When you give `apply` a data frame, the first thing it does is convert it to a matrix. When you want to apply a function to **columns** of a data frame, you are better off using `sapply` or `lapply` to avoid the conversion.

Comment: I will try both out! @Gregor - concerning 'apply' converting the data frame into a matrix: Will it be a problem to turn it into a data frame with 'as.data.frame()' afterwards? - Or will some of the properties of the data get lost in the proces?

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's only a tiny bit slower than the `c()` method. I was thinking it was doing `all(x != val)`.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the result, but a data frame is special in that each column can have its own class. A matrix can only have one class for the whole matrix. So if you have a data frame that has a bunch of numeric columns, some factors, a Date, and a character column, when you convert to a matrix *everything* gets converted to character - so yes, properties are lost.