# modify function to find the maximum length for a consecutive run of a number per row

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to modify the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50748483/counting-consecutive-values-in-rows-in-r) or have a new solution to include another column which shows the second largest consecutive run of "0". My sample data and code is below, the function is operating on the month columns and the `second largest run` column is what I hope to add. I am working with a large dataset so the more efficient the better, any ideas are appreciated, thanks.

sample data

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), V1 = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"), V2 = c(21, 233, 185, 
85, 208, 112, 238, 66, 38), V3 = c(149, 250, 218, 104, 62, 19, 
175, 168, 28), Jan = c(10, 20, 10, 12, 76, 28, 137, 162, 101), 
    Feb = c(20, 25, 15, 0, 89, 0, 152, 177, 119), March = c(0, 
    28, 20, 14, 108, 0, 165, 194, 132), April = c(0, 34, 25, 
    16, 125, 71, 181, 208, 149), May = c(25, 0, 30, 22, 135, 
    0, 191, 224, 169), June = c(29, 0, 35, 24, 145, 0, 205, 244, 
    187), July = c(34, 0, 40, 28, 163, 0, 217, 256, 207), August = c(37, 
    0, 45, 29, 173, 0, 228, 276, 221), Sep = c(0, 39, 50, 31, 
    193, 0, 239, 308, 236), Oct = c(0, 48, 55, 35, 210, 163, 
    252, 0, 247), Nov = c(48, 55, 60, 40, 221, 183, 272, 0, 264
    ), Dec = c(50, 60, 65, 45, 239, 195, 289, 0, 277), `Second largest run` = c(1, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA), result = c(2, 4, -Inf, 1, 
    -Inf, 5, -Inf, 3, -Inf)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

code

```
most_consecutive_val = function(x, val = 0) {
  with(rle(x), max(lengths[values == val]))
}


test$result=apply(test[,-c(1:4,17)], MARGIN = 1, most_consecutive_val)
```

Comment: Can you explain how is `Second largest run` column have values like 1, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than taking the `max` from the run length encoding (`rle`) function, we want to `sort` the output and then extract the desired index. We'll get NA's when we request an index that doesn't exist -- where there isn't a second run of zeroes in row 2 for example.

```
ordered_runs = function(x, val = 0, idx = 1) {
  with(rle(x), sort(lengths[values == val], decreasing = TRUE))[idx]
}

test$result_1 <- apply(test[,-c(1:4,17:18)], MARGIN = 1, ordered_runs, idx = 1)
test$result_2 <- apply(test[,-c(1:4,17:18)], MARGIN = 1, ordered_runs, idx = 2)
```

---

Output is slightly different than your expected -- (1) using NA's rather than -Inf, and (2) in your first row, where I believe there is a tie with a second run of 2 zeroes.

```
> test[,c(1,17:20)]
# A tibble: 9 x 5
     ID `Second largest run` result result_1 result_2
  <dbl>                <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>    <int>
1     1                    1      2        2        2
2     2                   NA      4        4       NA
3     3                   NA   -Inf       NA       NA
4     4                   NA      1        1       NA
5     5                   NA   -Inf       NA       NA
6     6                    2      5        5        2
7     7                   NA   -Inf       NA       NA
8     8                   NA      3        3       NA
9     9                   NA   -Inf       NA       NA
```

Comment: you are right the first row is a tie, this is perfect thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table` which should be quite fast for OP's large dataset and also identifies all sequences of zeros simultaneously:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
cols <- c("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

#convert into a long format
m <- melt(DF, measure.vars=cols)[
    #identify consecutive sequences of the same number and count
    order(ID), c("rl", "rw") := .(rl <- rleid(ID, value), rowid(rl))][
        #extract the last element where values = 0 (that is the length of sequences of zeros)
        value == 0L, .(ID=ID[.N], len=rw[.N]), rl][
            #sort in descending order for length of sequences
            order(ID, -len)]

#pivot into wide format and perform a update join
wide <- dcast(m, ID ~ rowid(ID), value.var="len")
DF[wide, on=.(ID), (names(wide)) := mget(names(wide))]
```

output:

```
   ID V1  V2  V3 Jan Feb March April May June July August Sep Oct Nov Dec  1  2
1:  1  A  21 149  10  20     0     0  25   29   34     37   0   0  48  50  2  2
2:  2  B 233 250  20  25    28    34   0    0    0      0  39  48  55  60  4 NA
3:  3  A 185 218  10  15    20    25  30   35   40     45  50  55  60  65 NA NA
4:  4  B  85 104  12   0    14    16  22   24   28     29  31  35  40  45  1 NA
5:  5  B 208  62  76  89   108   125 135  145  163    173 193 210 221 239 NA NA
6:  6  A 112  19  28   0     0    71   0    0    0      0   0 163 183 195  5  2
7:  7  A 238 175 137 152   165   181 191  205  217    228 239 252 272 289 NA NA
8:  8  B  66 168 162 177   194   208 224  244  256    276 308   0   0   0  3 NA
9:  9  B  38  28 101 119   132   149 169  187  207    221 236 247 264 277 NA NA
```

data:

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), V1 = c("A", 
    "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"), V2 = c(21, 233, 185, 
        85, 208, 112, 238, 66, 38), V3 = c(149, 250, 218, 104, 62, 19, 
            175, 168, 28), Jan = c(10, 20, 10, 12, 76, 28, 137, 162, 101), 
    Feb = c(20, 25, 15, 0, 89, 0, 152, 177, 119), March = c(0, 
        28, 20, 14, 108, 0, 165, 194, 132), April = c(0, 34, 25, 
            16, 125, 71, 181, 208, 149), May = c(25, 0, 30, 22, 135, 
                0, 191, 224, 169), June = c(29, 0, 35, 24, 145, 0, 205, 244, 
                    187), July = c(34, 0, 40, 28, 163, 0, 217, 256, 207), August = c(37, 
                        0, 45, 29, 173, 0, 228, 276, 221), Sep = c(0, 39, 50, 31, 
                            193, 0, 239, 308, 236), Oct = c(0, 48, 55, 35, 210, 163, 
                                252, 0, 247), Nov = c(48, 55, 60, 40, 221, 183, 272, 0, 264
                                ), Dec = c(50, 60, 65, 45, 239, 195, 289, 0, 277), `1` = c(2L, 
                                    4L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, NA), `2` = c(2L, NA, NA, NA, 
                                        NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```